# Wordpress's add_action for register_form not working

Tags: wordpress

From what I read in the net, the following code should be adding a "City" field in the user registration form of Wordpress.

Thing is that, it seems to be not working - I don't see the additional "City" field in the user form.

Any help appreciated.

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'extended_register_form' );
add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3);
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register');

    function extended_register_form() {
$city = ( isset( $_POST['city'] ) ) ? $_POST['city']: '';
?>
<p>
    <label for="city">City<br />
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($city)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
</p>
<?
}
function myplugin_registration_errors ($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['city'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'city_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a city.') );
    return $errors;
}
function myplugin_user_register ($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['city'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'city', $_POST['city']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked perfectly, perhaps it is because of the `<?` in line 12... Try `<?php` instead...

Where have you added the code? As a plugin or in the functions.php of your theme?

Comment: Thanks pfefferle. I am adding this to my functions.php file, where the only other code is a breadcrumb function.

Comment: Where have you used it before?

Comment: Could not understand, where have I used what before ?

Comment: Where have you used the code before trying to put it in the `functions.php`?

Comment: No, I have not tried to use the code anywhere before. I have added that directly to my functions.php and hoped that it would work from there. Which it didn't :(

Comment: Have you changed `<?` into `<?php` ?

Comment: Nope, but <? is working in my settings, so I don't know where from the  problem is coming. Having said that, and I found the PauPress plugin which was matching my requirement. I hence went with that. I am accepting your result since you are the only one who took the pain to reply :)

Answer (score 3):

Since Wordpress 3.0.0, the action to call is "signup_extra_fields" instead of "register_form", so you should use:

```
add_action( 'signup_extra_fields', 'extended_register_form' );
```